# Faster operation of appending an element to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to add a/multiple elements to a list and I have two options :

`mylist=mylist+newlist` or `(elemet)`

or `mylist.append(ele);`

which one will be faster?

Comment: You can profile it yourself using: `python -m cProfile yourscript.py`.

Comment: Don't delete the question once an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mylist.append(ele)` will be faster. This is documented in the Python Docs.

Quoting from the Docs -

```
The method append() shown in the example is defined for list objects; it adds a new element at the end of the list. In this example it is equivalent to result = result + [a], but more efficient.
```

`myList = myList + something` has to create a new list and reassign it.

Compare the `timeit` results -

```
>>> timeit('myList = myList + ["a"]', 'myList = []', number = 50000)
11.35058911138415
>>> timeit('myList.append("a")', 'myList = []', number = 50000)
0.010776052286637139
```